# Global variable at application level inside with out putting into Application_start

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-6, saml-2.0

I want to have a global variable at application level, now the thing is that the variable must not be in side Application_Start since it will be sustainable to IISRESET for getting updated. Is there any way to maintain a global variable at application level which can be updated without IISRESET.

Comment: Use a configuration file?

Comment: This sounds like a configuration that should be at the database level if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

There are three options,

1. Web.Config - where you can store custom application specific settings
2. Going back to db and store the settings and load on application reset or initial load.
3. Store in ASP.NET Cache/Enterprise library cache.